# ¿Cómo insertar datos a una tabla con id especifico?

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, crud, formulas

Me explico, tengo la siguiente tabla de productos: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que le doy al botón "Ver Formula" me lleva a la siguiente tabla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es agregar materia prima a cada producto. Es decir, que el botón "Ver formula" Me lleve a una tabla con un id propio que en este caso es el código de producto. No sé si para esto deba crear una tabla por cada producto o hay alguna forma de almacenar todos los datos de materias primas en cada producto sin necesidad de crear tantas tablas.

El objetivo final de esto es poder sumar el valor de todas las materia primas y así determinar el valor del producto.

Este es mi código para la tabla productos:

```html
    <table class="table table-striped table-dark table_id" id="table_id">


      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Linea</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php

        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "alcon");
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM producto ";
        $dato = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);

        if ($dato->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($dato)) {

        ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $fila['codigo']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila['linea']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?></td>




              <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="editar_producto.php?codigo=<?php echo $fila['codigo'] ?> ">
                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a>

                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="eliminar_producto.php?codigo=<?php echo $fila['codigo'] ?>">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../formula/formula.php?codigo=<?php echo $fila['codigo'] ?>">
                  Ver Formula</a>


              </td>
            </tr>


          <?php
          }
        } else {

          ?>
          <tr class="text-center">
            <td colspan="16">No existen registros</td>
          </tr>


        <?php

        }

        ?>


        </body>
    </table>
```

Una vez le doy al botón "Ver formula" me redirige a la pagina "formula.php" el código es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <br>
  <div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="agregar_mp_formula.php"> Agregar Materia Prima 
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../producto/productos.php">Productos</a>



  </div>





            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Formula de: <?php echo $usuario['descripcion']; ?></h1>

                        <table class="table table-striped table-dark table_id" id="table_id">


<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Codigo MP</th>
    <th>Descripcion MP</th>
    <th>Coste/Kg</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>

  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "alcon");
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM formula ";
$dato = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);

if ($dato->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($dato)) {

?>
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila['codigo_mp']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['linea']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?></td>




        <td>

          <a class="btn btn-danger" href="eliminar_formula.php?codigo_mp=<?php echo $fila['codigo_mp'] ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

        </td>
      </tr>


    <?php
    }
  } else {

    ?>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td colspan="16">No existen registros</td>
    </tr>


  <?php

  }

  ?>


  </body>
</table>
              </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Total: <span id="total" class="badge badge-light"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Al presionar el boton "Agregar materia prima" Me lleva a esta interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco en esta interfaz, es seleccionar las materias primas ya existentes, para agregarlas a "formula.php" con el id correspondiente asignado a esa interfaz. El problema es que los productos se agregan a la misma tabla, independientemente del id del producto al cual queremos agregarle materias primas. Código de "agregar_mp_formula.php"

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <br>
  <div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="agregar_mp_formula.php"> Agregar Materia Prima 
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../producto/productos.php">Productos</a>



  </div>





            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Formula de: <?php echo $usuario['descripcion']; ?></h1>

                        <table class="table table-striped table-dark table_id" id="table_id">


<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Codigo MP</th>
    <th>Descripcion MP</th>
    <th>Coste/Kg</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>

  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "alcon");
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM formula ";
$dato = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);

if ($dato->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($dato)) {

?>
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila['codigo_mp']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['linea']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?></td>




        <td>

          <a class="btn btn-danger" href="eliminar_formula.php?codigo_mp=<?php echo $fila['codigo_mp'] ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

        </td>
      </tr>


    <?php
    }
  } else {

    ?>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td colspan="16">No existen registros</td>
    </tr>


  <?php

  }

  ?>


  </body>
</table>
              </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Total: <span id="total" class="badge badge-light"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Adicionalmente, esta es mi base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es una decisión de diseño que vos vas a tener que tomar. Esta pregunta se basa en opiniones. Podes hacerlo como vos quieras, pero yo que vos me sentaría a formular preguntas sobre las "materias primas". Por ejemplo: ¿Voy a necesitar saber cuantos productos requieren una misma materia prina? ¿me sirve tener un código de materia prima? Si quisiera crear el producto X y el Y, ¿Necesito saber cuanto tengo que comprar de la materia prima Z? etc.

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
También puedes aprovechar y hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Todo lo que pregutnas, depende de tus reglas de negocio y lo que quieras hacer. no hay una respuesta correcta... trata de enfocar mas la pregunta...